# Converting doc / docx files to pdf in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf-conversion

Is there a good library which can convert doc file to pdf? There are some paid options available like cloudconvert, convertApi etc but I am looking for a free option. My python app is hosted on EC2 machine.
I also looked at python-docx library which can allow me to read the contents of the doc file, but writing the contents to pdf file will break the styling I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA solution for you (I don't know how to do this using Python).

If you need to convert multiple Word files to other formats, like TXT, RTF, HTML or PDF, run the script below.

```
Option Explicit On

Sub ChangeDocsToTxtOrRTFOrHTML()
    'with export to PDF in Word 2007
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim tFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim strDocName As String
    Dim intPos As Integer
    Dim locFolder As String
    Dim fileType As String
    On Error Resume Next

    locFolder = InputBox("Enter the folder path to DOCs", "File Conversion", "C:\Users\your_path_here\")
    Select Case Application.Version
        Case Is < 12
            Do
                fileType = UCase(InputBox("Change DOC to TXT, RTF, HTML", "File Conversion", "TXT"))
            Loop Until (fileType = "TXT" Or fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "HTML")
        Case Is >= 12
            Do
                fileType = UCase(InputBox("Change DOC to TXT, RTF, HTML or PDF(2007+ only)", "File Conversion", "TXT"))
            Loop Until (fileType = "TXT" Or fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "HTML" Or fileType = "PDF")
    End Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder)
    Set tFolder = fs.CreateFolder(locFolder & "Converted")
    Set tFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder & "Converted")

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Dim d As Document
        Set d = Application.Documents.Open(oFile.Path)
        strDocName = ActiveDocument.Name
        intPos = InStrRev(strDocName, ".")
        strDocName = Left(strDocName, intPos - 1)
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory tFolder
        Select Case fileType
            Case Is = "TXT"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".txt"
                ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatText
        Case Is = "RTF"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".rtf"
                ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatRTF
        Case Is = "HTML"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".html"
                ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatFilteredHTML
        Case Is = "PDF"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".pdf"
                ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=strDocName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
        End Select
        d.Close
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory oFolder
    Next oFile
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aspose.Words Cloud SDK for Python. It supports DOC/DOCX to PDF conversion and keeps the formatting/styling intact. Its free trial plan provides 150 monthly API calls.

P.S: I am a developer evangelist at Aspose.

```
# For complete examples and data files, please go to https://github.com/aspose-words-cloud/aspose-words-cloud-python
# Import module
import asposewordscloud
import asposewordscloud.models.requests
from shutil import copyfile

# Please get your Client ID and Secret from https://dashboard.aspose.cloud.
client_id='xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx'
client_secret='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

words_api = asposewordscloud.WordsApi(client_id,client_secret)
words_api.api_client.configuration.host='https://api.aspose.cloud'

filename = 'C:/Temp/02_pages.docx'
dest_name = 'C:/Temp/02_pages.pdf'
#Convert DOCX to PDF
request = asposewordscloud.models.requests.ConvertDocumentRequest(document=open(filename, 'rb'), format='pdf')
result = words_api.convert_document(request)
copyfile(result, dest_name)
print("Result {}".format(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

from docx2pdf import convert

# The location where the files are located
input_path = r'c:\Folder7\input'
# The location where we will write the PDF files
output_path = r'c:\Folder7\output'

# Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
os.makedirs(output_path, exist_ok=True)

# Check if the input directory exists
directory_path = Path(input_path)
if not directory_path.exists() or not directory_path.is_dir():
    print(directory_path, "is invalid")
    sys.exit(1)

# Convert each .docx file to .pdf
for file_path in directory_path.glob("*.docx"):
    print("Converting file:", file_path)
    output_file_path = os.path.join(output_path, file_path.stem + ".pdf")
    convert(file_path, output_file_path)
    print("Converted file:", file_path, "to", output_file_path)
```